# Enable CORS for Azure File Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage-files

I have a SAS link for file from Azure File Storage and I want to use this link in iframe

```
<iframe src = "http://localhost:8077/ViewerJS/index.html#https://myazureaccount.file.core.windows.net/myshare/mydirectorypath/myfile?SASTOKEN" width='300' height='300'></iframe>
```

Or send simple HttpRequest

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('GET', "https://myazureaccount.file.core.windows.net/myshare/mydirectorypath/myfile?SASTOKEN");
http.send();
```

I enable CORS for my server in Azure

[image: CORS Settings]

But I see error:

Failed to load https: //myazureaccount.file.core.windows.net/myshare/mydirectorypath/myfile?SASTOKEN": No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http: //localhost:8077' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Please try by changing `ALLOWED HEADERS` and `EXPOSED HEADERS` to `*`.

Comment: Changed, but error is reproduced

Comment: Hi, could you email azurefiles at microsoft.com, we would like to follow up with you so we can understand the root cause and post back a response.

Comment: Sorry, where I could find the full email address for "azurefiles at microsoft.com"?)

Comment: Do you try to use the wildcard character '*' to allow all origin domains to make requests?